# Proof: Let $P$ be a p–Sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $N_{G}(P)$ such that $|H|=p^{s}$. Show that $H \subset P$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $P$ be a p–Sylow subgroup of a finite group $G$. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $N_{G}(P)$ such that $|H|=p^{s}$. Show that $H \subset P$.

Can someone please give some pointers about how should I start with this proof and where do I want to get to at the end? Thanks!

Comment: $HP$ is a $p$-group containing $P$ so it must equal $P$.

Comment: By definition $hp=p,\forall p\in P$ and $h\in H$, so yes $HP=P$. But how does that help me to show $H\subset P$?

Comment: $H \subset P$ follows trivially from $HP=P$. (If $\subset$ was intended to denote strict containment, then the assertion is false, because $H=P$ is possible.)

Comment: Of course! Basic group property requires $H\subset P$ ($\subset$ should really include improper subset like you suggested) if $HP=P$. Duh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$P \unlhd N_G(P)$, so is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. $HP$ is a $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, since $P$ is normal and $|HP|=\frac{|H| \cdot |P|}{|H \cap P|}$. But $P$ is the only maximal $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$, hence $HP \subseteq P$. You can take it from here ...

Comment: $P \unlhd N_G(P)$, so is the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(P)$. Could you elaborate a bit on that please? Is it a theorem?

Comment: @AllenAi Perhaps you need to go over Sylow theorems more carefully again: a Sylow subgroup of some group is normal in it iff it is **the only Sylow subgroup there is**

Comment: Thanks @DonAntonio, in addition, perhaps superfluous to remark, but $N_G(P)$ normalizes $P$ by definition, that is $P \unlhd N_G(P)$ and always $\{P\}=Syl_p(N_G(P))$.

Comment: @DonAntonio, and Nicky. Indeed. Thank you.